# Talend Execution Fails to Generate Code

Tags: java, java-8, talend

I'm trying to build the first example job from talend (http://www.talendforge.org/tutorials/tutorial.php?language=english&idTuto=1#Action)

When I attempt to run it, I get the following errors:

```
Execution failed : Failed to generate code. [----------
1. ERROR in C:\Talend\workspace\.JETEmitters\src\org\talend\designer\codegen\translators\technical\TSortOutBeginJava.java (at line 1)   package org.talend.designer.codegen.translators.technical;  ^ The type java.util.Map$Entry cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
----------
2. ERROR in C:\Talend\workspace\.JETEmitters\src\org\talend\designer\codegen\translators\technical\TSortOutBeginJava.java (at line 421)     stringBuffer.append(TEXT_1);    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ The type java.lang.CharSequence cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
---------- 2 problems (2 errors)]
```

I've tried changing window>preferences>talend>java interpreter to point to the jdk installation as well as the jre7 and jre8 installations, all to no avail.

Additionally, I've tried executing sample jobs provided by talend's big data demo and received the same error messages

Comment: Can you check your JAVA_HOME and path system environment variables? They should point to your JDK. It's also worth noting that, AFAIK, Talend doesn't currently support Java 8 (1.8.x JDKs)

Comment: JAVA_HOME and _PATH point to the jdk1.8.0_05 folder. I'll try getting an older jdk

Comment: I had to uninstall my jdk1.8.0_05 as well as my jre8; after that, thinks went (relatively) well. Talend does not support java8

Comment: I'll try and find some mention of it somewhere and post it as an answer for other readers. I only happen to know it because a consultant mentioned it in passing a few weeks back.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Talend [doesn't currently support Java 8](https://help.talend.com/display/KB/Java+8+Support). This is as of 5.4 although I'd have to check 5.5 but I believe that is still the case and I think likely to be the case for 5.6 too.

You shouldn't have to uninstall any 1.8.x JDKs, just make sure that your JAVA_HOME and Path system environment variables are pointing to a 1.7.x JDK (and that this 1.7.x JDK is first in the list).

Comment: Ah; I disabled Java 8, but now realize I should have Moved 7 up on the list as well

Comment: Note that I had to re-import the project to make it work after the downgrade to java 7.